# Bucketing data into weekly, bi-weekly, monthly and quarterly data in R

Tags: r, date

I have a data frame with two columns. Date, Gender

I want to change the Date column to the start of the week for that observation. For example if  Jun-28-2011 is a Tuesday, I'd like to change it to Jun-27-2011. Basically I want to re-label Date fields such that two data points that are in the same week have the same Date.

I also want to be able to do it by-weekly, or monthly and specially quarterly.

Update:
Let's use this as a dataset.

```
datset <- data.frame(date = as.Date("2011-06-28")+c(1:100))
```

Comment: with a rep of 963 I would have thought you could write a question that at the very least includes some sample data, and maybe even some sample code showing what you have already tried.

Comment: I added a sample dataset

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One slick way to do this that I just learned recently is to use the `lubridate` package:

```
library(lubridate)
datset <- data.frame(date = as.Date("2011-06-28")+c(1:100))
#Add 1, since floor_date appears to round down to Sundays
floor_date(datset$date,"week") + 1
```

I'm not sure about how to do bi-weekly binning, but monthly and quarterly are easily handled with the respective `base` functions:

```
quarters(datset$date)
months(datset$date)
```

EDIT: Interestingly, `floor_date` from `lubridate` does not appear to be able to round down to the nearest quarter, but the function of the same name in `ggplot2` does.

Comment: Lubridate can round by quarter as of version 1.5, although not to 2-weeks as far as I can tell.
Be careful, floor_date() keeps the timezone information, so if you're using the dates as e.g. histogram bins, "March 1 EST" is different from "March 1 EDT".  :(

Answer (score 6):

Look at `?strftime`. In particular, the following formats:

> `%b`: Abbreviated month name in the
>   current locale. (Also matches full
>   name on input.)
>
> `%B`: Full month name
>   in the current locale. (Also matches
>   abbreviated name on input.)
>
> `%m`: Month as decimal number (01–12).
>
> `%W`: Week of the year as decimal number
>   (00–53) using Monday as the first day
>   of week (and typically with the first
>   Monday of the year as day 1 of week
>   1). The UK convention.

eg:

```
> strftime("2011-07-28","Month: %B, Week: %W")
[1] "Month: July, Week: 30"

> paste("Quarter:",ceiling(as.integer(strftime("2011-07-28","%m"))/3))
[1] "Quarter: 3"
```